# AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'get', after apply 'style.applymap'

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
df1 = df1.style.applymap(lambda x: '' if x<50 else "background-color: darkgreen" ,subset=['%_pedido_centralizado','%_pedido_manual','%sum_pedido_manual_centralizado'])
```

But, when use the following code to plot the graph:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7))
sns.barplot(x="MTRL_PROD_HIERCY_2", y='%sum_pedido_manual_centralizado', data=df1, ci=None, estimator=sum)
```

Return this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Can someone help me on how to solve this problem?

Comment: please post the whole traceback/.

Comment: You have to use data=df1.data since this is a styler object.

Comment: Pygirl, I can't post the traceback here :(